# how to fix (Hidden field submitted_by) This field is required error in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to hide the submitted by field in my forms.py because I don't want user to upload the assignment on the behalf of some other user. So what I am doing is I am hiding the field but before hiding I am setting the value of logged in user to that input text using javascript but I am getting this error. (Hidden field submitted_by) This field is required.
forms.py

```
    class assignmentUploadForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Submissions
            fields = ('submitted_by', 'submitted_to',
                      'submission_title', 'submission_file', 'submission_status')
    
            widgets = {
                'submitted_by': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'type': 'hidden', 'id': 'user', 'value': ''}),
                'submitted_to': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                'submission_title': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            }

template 


 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin-left: 240px;">
                {% csrf_token %}
               
                {{form.as_p}}
                <input type="submit">
  var name = "{{user.username}}"
        document.getElementById('user').value = name;

views.py 
class AddAssignmentView(CreateView):

    model = Submissions
    form_class = assignmentUploadForm
    template_name = 'project/assignment.html'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be better to not have it in the form at all.

All someone needs to do is inspect element and change the type from hidden.

You can set the value of submitted_by to the current user in the form_valid()

```
class assignmentUploadForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Submissions
        fields = ('submitted_to', 'submission_title', 
                  'submission_file', 'submission_status')

        widgets = {
            'submitted_to': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'submission_title': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }


class AddAssignmentView(CreateView):
    model = Submissions
    form_class = assignmentUploadForm
    template_name = 'project/assignment.html'
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.submitted_by = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: perfect, got it. I am getting and errror can you help me this?    ValueError at /assignment_submit/
Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: adeel808>>": "Submissions.submitted_by" must be a "Student" instance. This is my submissions model
 submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    submission_file = models.FileField(null=False, blank=True, default='')
    submitted_to = models.ForeignKey(
        Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    submission_title = models.ForeignKey(
        Assignment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

Comment: So request.user is the User object. How do you link your user to a student object?
It looks like submitted_by is pointing to the student object so you need to go to your User and get the field that stores the student.

Comment: yes you are right, submitted by is linked to student and student has  field student_usernameis linked to User.           
class Student(models.Model):
    student_username = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                           )            
class Submissions(models.Model):
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)... DO I need some changes in form_valid function?

Comment: So in the form_valid instead of self.object.submitted_by = self.request.user, you need to get the student object.
self.object.submitted_by = Student.objects.get(student_username=self.request.user)

Comment: thnkyou sooooooooo much, you are such a life savior, I was trying this for days, stucked badly. you are an angel